# How can we use import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.CatalystSqlParser in Pyspark

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

How can we use

> import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.CatalystSqlParser in Pyspark, it is working fine in Scala, now as per demand we try to convert our project in Pyspark. i am using azure data-bricks to use this  library.

Comment: If you want to use these low level Spark features use Scala. I´m afraid that pySpark is not designed for using these things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for feedback, still waiting for some help

Answer (score 0):

> Note - CatalystSqlParser is used to translate DataTypes from their
> canonical string representation (e.g. **when adding fields to a schema
> or casting column to a different data type**) or StructTypes.

In PySpark, you can cast or change the DataFrame column data type using `cast()` function of Column class.

Sample code github [link](https://github.com/spark-examples/pyspark-examples/blob/master/pyspark-cast-column.py)

Refer this [article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-cast-column-type/) for more information

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.CatalystSqlParser;def toSparkType(inputType: String): DataType = CatalystSqlParser.parseDataType(inputType)
    def getSchema(inputType: String) : StructType = StructType(inputType.split(",").map(line ⇒ line.split(" ")).map(field => StructField(field(0),toSparkType(field(1)),true)))
    val NewFileSchema = getSchema(Source_Schema_V) 
val NewFileDF = spark.read.option("header", "true").schema(NewFileSchema).csv(Source_File)

Comment: value of Source_Schema_V="ID int,FirstName string,LastName string,Department string,Created_Date string,LastUpdated_Date string"

Comment: Then how this code , converted in Pyspark. it is working fine in scala

Comment: is this is limitations of  Pyspark